# Re-Authenitcating a facebook user once logged in

Tags: php, facebook

Given that a Facebook user has logged in at some point in your Facebookapp (using fb.login) and that user has been saved in the database. How can you let the user re-authenticate with you app again after the accesstoken has expired (fb.api('/me') fails).

The signed request holds the user id, but how do you log in the user from there?

I'm using the PHP sdk and I basicly check with FB.api('/me') right in the beginning to either direct to a welcome page or the users page. But FB return false in some cases, usually after a day or 2. So I started to think it was because of the Accesstoken has expired. I have no clue how to re-authenticate, I only have knowledge that the user id still resides in the signed request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript SDK to prompt the user to login via Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Alternatively, you could try storing the code returned by Facebook during [server-side auth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) and use it to request a new token when the user returns.

Comment: I'm looking for a automated matter, in the background, serverside. Showing a popup again (even if it autoclses) is not very user friendly. Alsoo javascript redirects are nasty (load index.html, then a popup, then redirect to welcome.html)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ is probably more applicable for deciding whether or not to display the login button

Comment: He asks for help with PHP Facebook SDK.. just stating "Use Javascript SDK" isn't really helpfull.

Comment: @user1132028 If the access token has expired, the user has to login again via FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/

Comment: @Gidogeek I didn't say "Use the JS SDK". He has to prompt the user to login again. The easiest way to achieve this is to use the JS SDK.

Comment: How about the signed_request method (#3 in the docs)? In the background I use the PHP SDK, and I use FB.getUser() to authenticate the user. getUser() consists of a check of the existence of user_id in the signed_request. I have a feeling, that the sdk gets the accesstoken from a session which last longer then the one from facebook. Authenticating with JS SDK is not an option. The user is asked permission on the end of the app for better conversion. But on return I have to welcome him. Thats why I check fb.api('/me') on entry.

Answer (score 0):

Put following code in your javascript...it will open login popup if user is not logged in

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

```
if (response.authResponse) {  
     fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
     token = response.authResponse.accessToken; 
 } else {  
     FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
            token = response.authResponse.accessToken;  
        }
        else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');  
        }
    });

    }
```

},true);

Comment: Again, I can't use the javascript sdk for pre-authentication. The user is asked to authenticate at the end of the app using javascript sdk. When he returns after a few days I need to check with the php sdk, else users that see the app for the first time, are immedietly prompted with a popup. Thats extremely user unfriendly and you will lose conversion.

So again, how do you I log the user in, having a signed_request WITHOUT javascript sdk. It needs to be server side and anomynous (the user doesnt notice since he already gave permissions)